# What is Microsoft Media Foundation's equivalent of Directshow's custom video filters?

Tags: c++, c, com, directshow, ms-media-foundation

In the same way where we can make custom directshow filters to make a virtual cam/mic (and then select this virtual cam in another program like skype for example), what would be the equivalent to that feature in Media Foundation? Since MF is going to replace DS, i decided i would try to make my program future proof of some sorts and would like a starting point. Any ideas/tuts/links etc would be greatly appreviated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Media Foundation employs the concept of [Media Sources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms697527%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which are close to DirectShow virtual devices.

> Media sources are objects that generate media data in the Media Foundation pipeline. This section describes the media source APIs in detail. Read this section if you are implementing a custom media source, or using a media source outside of the Media Foundation pipeline.

While you are supposedly aware of multiple apps that would connect to your custom DirectShow source, you are going to have hard time trying to find something to connect to source implemented in Media Foundation: Skype does not yet attempt to leverage them.

You will find good samples there: [Media Foundation Sample Code](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/mediafoundation)

Comment: Coolbeans. I'll have to look into those examples.